# how this join statement work to produce this result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

hi i am learning `MySQL` joins . from a tutorial i got two tables .

[image]

the query is

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
// Construct our join query
$query = "SELECT family.Position, food.Meal ".
 "FROM family, food ".
    "WHERE family.Position = food.Position";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['Position']. " - ". $row['Meal'];
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

and the result is

[image]

*my problem is , what is this selection logic. 
*if you started by getting an `family` table position and search it in food table , i think the result should be

```
Dad|steak
Dad|Tacos
Mom|Salad
```

but the result is different . how the search works and result set organized . please help me to understand how this works , thank you in advance ...............

Comment: use `INNER JOIN` for the desired output

Comment: @diEcho , yes i know how to use inner , left and right join . but the thing is , i want to know how the result set is processed internally. is food table's position value is compared with every position value in family table's position value or vice versa .

Comment: Sql is declarative language - you say what you want, and it tries to perform most efficient query. In this instance optimizer took `n` table in `1:n` relationship as primary source. Remember also that Sql does not guarantee order of rows. You need to explicitly order them.

Comment: for ordering the result you can use `order by` clause..

at the end of your query you can write `order by family.Position`

Comment: @nikola , hm that is what i asked , thank you very much , so it is handled differently in different cases !

Comment: You will benefit by adopting proper join syntax. Distinction between joining and filtering will greatly simplify reading queries.

Comment: you said this "hi i am learning MySQL joins . from a tutorial i got two tables ." so you are a beginner

Comment: @jcho360 :) . hmm actually i am trying to learn , what is really happening inside

Comment: [Jeff Atwood has a great explanation of SQL joins up on his blog from 2007.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite this query:

```
SELECT
   family.Position, food.Meal
FROM
   family
   JOIN food USING (Position)
```

You can use the `WHERE` clause for `JOIN` conditions -- MySQL will optimize it either way, but typically syntax that uses `ON`/`USING` for `JOIN` conditions is preferred.  You could also use a `NATURAL JOIN` here, but that may be unsafe.

As for your specific question, I don't know why MySQL orders things one way or the other.  The only thing I can tell you is that you should not depend on the order of results if you do not specify an `ORDER  BY` clause.  You should treat the order as random.  It seems like it is ordering by `Meal` rather than `Position`.  I don't know why that would be, but even *that* may not be dependable.  When order matters, use `ORDER BY`.